# SQL Express Server 2012 Upgrade to standard 2014 architecture Missmatch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have an **SQL Express Server 2012** which I would like to upgrade to **SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition**.

My SQL version is x64 as you can see as per the select `@@version` query

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)  
Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation    
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

But when I ran the setup to upgrade I received an error.

I'm using this command:

```
setup /ACTION=editionupgrade /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /PID=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

This is the error message:

> Rule "Upgrade Architecture Mismatch" Failed the CPU architecture of
>   upgrading feature(s) and this installation program are different. To
>   upgrade there features, setup architecture must be the same as the
>   features being installed.

The bizarre thing it's that I also tried with the x86 CD and I received the same error.

I am incline to believe that this has something to do with the 32 features installed by the x64 version and also that I've installed SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This should be asked in DBA forums http://dba.stackexchange.com/ you'll be more likely to get some help

Comment: [This](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/SQL-Server-Architecture-mismatch-during-edition-upgrade.html) or [this](https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/microsoft-backoffice/sql-server-2005-2008-2008-r2-2012/57998-upgrade-architecture-mismatch) should help, may be!

Comment: Already tried those options but not help.
I have two media, one x86 and one x64 so I don't have an option to select x86 or x64, are grey out

Comment: Remove everything that didn't mention x64 but still the same issue.